# Can't run GUI while installing Oracle in Linux from a jar file

Tags: linux, permissions, java, oracle, installation

I'm trying to install an oracle product in Linux using a jar. When I run the command "java -jar installer.jar" using the root user, the installer's GUI shows up without problems.

But if I try to run the same command using the oracle user, I get "Unable to instantiate GUI, defaulting to console mode" and the installer proceeds in the console. What permissions must be assigned to the oracle user, so it can run the installer under the GUI? I created the oracle user with these commands:

```
groupadd -g 500 oinstall
groupadd -g 501 admin
mkdir -p /apps/oracle
mkdir -p /var/opt/oracle
useradd -u 500 -d /home/oracle -g oinstall -G admin -s /bin/bash oracle
chown oracle:admin /apps/oracle /var/opt/oracle
passwd oracle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines (as root) solved my problem:

```
xhost +
su - oracle
```

Comment: Yes, and they gave the entire world access to your desktop.

Answer (score 2):

You may also solve this problem installing  libXtst.i686. In my case, it solves the problem (Oracle Linux x64).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably logged in as root in the GUI, right? The installer doesn't have access to launch XWindows applications as Oracle into a GUI process owned/running by root. Login to the GUI as the oracle software owner.

Answer (score 0):

How are you becoming the other user?  Are you using su, sudo, ssh as the user, or what?  One quick an easy way to get a GUI as an alternate user without messing around with xauth environment variables or anything would be to to simply SSH to that user with the `-X` option to enable X11 forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by :

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

You can test it by running `xclock`. If the analog clock widget opens in your local machine, you can run other programs that launch windows installer from Linux OS.